# How to save and load position of qraphicsitems to qraphicscene or (correctly drow item)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

In principle, not a difficult task, but everything turned out to be not as easy as it seems. It is very difficult to understand the coordinates. For there are three pairs of them: the model, the Item, the view. I am keeping the x and y positions and the rest of the class properties. Then I try to add them back using the current position. This is where the magic begins. Elements take positions that were clearly not there before. This is also clearly related to the implementation of the move items function. However, it is not mine and I do not understand how to correctly set the coordinates, both at the beginning and at the end. There is also a function to zoom in and out of the scene, it is possible and it also affects the subsequent loading, however I already have no ideas.

Before load

[image]

after load

[image]

My MRE implement

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from  math import pi
import os
from pickle import load,dump

class MyQGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__ (self, parent=None):
        super(MyQGraphicsView, self).__init__ (parent)


    def wheelEvent(self, event):

        if QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
            print('Control+Click')
        # Zoom Factor
            zoomInFactor = 1.25
            zoomOutFactor = 1 / zoomInFactor

            # Set Anchors
            self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)
            self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)

            # Save the scene pos
            oldPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

            # Zoom
            if event.delta() > 0:
                zoomFactor = zoomInFactor
            else:
                zoomFactor = zoomOutFactor
            self.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)

            # Get the new position
            newPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

            # Move scene to old position
            delta = newPos - oldPos
            self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())

class Communicate(QObject):
    closeApp = Signal()
    add_delete_row = Signal(QModelIndex, str)

class Drow_equipent(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h,name,brush=Qt.blue,type='эллипс'):
        super().__init__()
        self.setPos(x, y)
        self.penWidth = 1
        self.name=name
        self.x,self.y,self.h,self.w=x,y,h,w
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.signal=Communicate()
        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges|QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.rotation_=False
        self._brush=QBrush(brush)
        self.pen_color=Qt.black
        self.type_obj=type
        self.types = {'эллипс': lambda x: x.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h),'прямоугольник':lambda x: x.drawRect(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)}
                                            # x.drawLine(QPoint(self.x+self.x*2,self.y+self.y*2),QPoint(self.w_eq-self.w_eq/8,self.h_eq-self.h_eq/8)),
                                            # x.drawLine(QPoint(self.x+self.x*8,self.y+self.y*8),QPoint(self.x+self.x*4,self.y+self.y*4+self.h_eq/8)),
                                            # x.drawLine(QPoint(self.x, self.y), QPoint(5, self.y)),
                                            # x.drawLine(QPoint(self.w_eq,self.h_eq), QPoint(self.w_eq, self.h_eq-5)),
                                            # x.drawLine(QPoint(self.w_eq, self.h_eq), QPoint(self.w_eq-5, self.h_eq)),





    def get_file_settings(self):

        c=self.scenePos()


        return {'x':c.x(),'y':c.y(),'h':self.h,'w':self.w,'name':self.name,'rotation':self.rotation(),
                'brush_color':self._brush.color().toTuple(),'type_obj':self.type_obj}


    def createDefaultContextMenu(self):
        menu = QMenu()
        menu.addAction('Повернуть').triggered.connect(lambda: self.setMode('scale'))
        return menu

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        QApplication.instance().setOverrideCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        QApplication.instance().restoreOverrideCursor()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        if self.rotation_:
            self.my_rotation(self.rotation()+1)
            return True


        orig_cursor_position = event.lastScenePos()
        updated_cursor_position = event.scenePos()
        orig_position = self.scenePos()
        updated_cursor_x = updated_cursor_position.x() - orig_cursor_position.x() + orig_position.x()
        updated_cursor_y = updated_cursor_position.y() - orig_cursor_position.y() + orig_position.y()



        self.setPos(QPointF(updated_cursor_x, updated_cursor_y))




    def createDefaultContextMenu(self):
        menu = QMenu()

        menu.addAction('Повернуть').triggered.connect(lambda: self.setMode(True))

        return menu



    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
            menu = self.createDefaultContextMenu()

            menu.exec_(event.screenPos())

    def setMode(self, mode):
        self.rotation_ = mode

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print('x: {0}, y: {1}'.format(self.pos().x(), self.pos().y()))
        if self.rotation_:
            self.rotation_=False

    def my_rotation(self,angle):
        # self.prepareGeometryChange()
        c=self.mapToScene(self.boundingRect().center())
        self.setRotation(angle)
        cNew = self.mapToScene(self.boundingRect().center())
        offset = c - cNew
        self.moveBy(offset.x(), offset.y())


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        print(event.pos())


    def boundingRect(self):
        # return QRectF(-10 - penWidth / 2, -10 - penWidth / 2,
        #               20 + penWidth, 20 + penWidth)

        return QRectF(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h)
        # return QRectF(self.x,self.y,self.w_eq,self.h_eq)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget, PySide2_QtWidgets_QWidget=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # painter.drawRoundedRect(-10, -10, 20, 20, 5, 5)
        # painter.setBrush()

        painter.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing|QPainter.TextAntialiasing,True)

        painter.setPen(self.pen_color)

        painter.setBrush(self._brush)


        self.types[self.type_obj](painter)
        self._brush = painter.brush()



    def setBrush(self,brush):
        self._brush.setColor(brush)

    def get_square(self):
        type={'эллипс': round ((((pi*self.w*self.h)/4)/10000),4),
              'прямоугольник':(self.h*self.w)/10000}
        return  type[self.type_obj]

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setGeometry(0, 0, 600, 700)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.graphicsView = MyQGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName(u"graphicsView")
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self.graphicsView)
        self.scene.setObjectName('scene')
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.graphicsView.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)

        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.add_item = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.add_item.setObjectName(u"add_item")

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.add_item)

        self.save_items = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.save_items.setObjectName(u"save_items")

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.save_items)

        self.load_items = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.load_items.setObjectName(u"load_items")

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.load_items)

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 600, 700)

        self.add_item.pressed.connect(self.add_equipment)
        self.save_items.pressed.connect(self.save_items_)
        self.load_items.pressed.connect(self.load_items_)

        self.retranslateUi()


    # setupUi


    def retranslateUi(self):

        self.add_item.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"add item", None))
        self.save_items.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"save items", None))
        self.load_items.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"load items", None))
    # retranslateUi


    def add_equipment(self):
        self.eq_obj = Drow_equipent(30, 40, 20,
                                    20, 'block', Qt.blue,'прямоугольник')

        self.scene.addItem(self.eq_obj)
        self.last_selected_item = self.eq_obj


    def load_items_(self):
        with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'config.ini'), 'rb') as f:
            settings = load(f)
        print(settings)

        items_keys = [key for key in settings.keys() if key != 'grid']
        print(items_keys)
        for item in items_keys:
            self.eq_obj = Drow_equipent(settings[item]['x'], settings[item]['y'],
                                        settings[item]['w'], settings[item]['h'],
                                        settings[item]['name'],
                                        QBrush(QColor().fromRgb(*settings[item]['brush_color'])),
                                        settings[item]['type_obj'])
            
            self.scene.addItem(self.eq_obj)


    def save_items_(self):
        settings = {}
        number_item = 0
        for item in self.scene.items():
            settings[f'item_№:{number_item}'] = item.get_file_settings()
            number_item += 1
        with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'config.ini'), 'wb') as f:
            dump(settings, f)


if __name__ == '__main__':

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        translator = QTranslator()
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            locale = sys.argv[1]
        else:
            locale = QLocale.system().name()
        translator.load('qt_%s' % locale,
                        QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
        app.installTranslator(translator)

        window = MainWindow()
        window.show()
        app.exec_()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: While waiting for the MRE, from what I can see there's clearly a problem: the given `x` and `y` coordinates are used for the position, but also for drawing; the result is that if X is 5 and Y is 10, drawing would happen at 10x20, and that because painting is always relative to the item's position, so I would start from that issue. Then, both `x` and `y` are properties of a QGraphicsItem, so they should **never** be overwritten with other data.

Comment: @musicamante thank you for watch and write comment!

Comment: @musicamante it is still not understood where the error is

Comment: @Valvea as said in the first comment, you need to provide us a MRE. Please carefully read that link and follow its suggestions. You must provide the **minimal** code in order to allow us to *reproduce* your issue (which means that we should be easily able to copy, paste and run your code), and any part of the code that is not related to this issue should be removed.

Comment: @musicamante sorry for the not understanding. I write MRE and now understand what that mean. thank you.

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry too)

Comment: @but problem not solve(

Comment: Please consider that while the code is now reproducible, it still is **not** minimal, as it contains a lot of completely unnecessary parts: making a *good* example takes a **lot of time** (even *hours*!), so you should never rush that passage, especially if you think that you're in a hurry: debugging hundreds of lines of code is *your* job, we should only focus on the issue without being distracted by unrelated code (or unnecessary commented lines): our time is as precious as yours. Also, please take more care about code styling, and avoid excessive use of blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *very* important thing to always consider is that the *position* of a QGraphicsItem doesn't have to match its contents.

Consider two rectangle items:

```
rect1 = self.scene.addRect(5, 10, 20, 10)
rect2 = self.scene.addRect(0, 0, 20, 10)
rect2.setPos(5, 10)
```

While they are both shown at the same position, they are **not** the same. Those parameters are actually what will become the `boundingRect` of those items, but while the `pos` of the first is still at (0, 0), the second has been moved, and that's because a graphics item **always** has its starting position at coordinates (0, 0), and the bounding rect is *always* in item coordinates.

When creating new items it's usually good practice to set their bounding rect positioned at (0, 0), unless special requirements are needed (for instance, an item that is always shown *centered* on its position).

Before showing how to correct your code, there are other issues it's important to clear out.

- if you need to allow moving items, it's usually not necessary to implement moving on your own, as the QGraphicsItem flag `ItemIsMovable` is enough; if you need special control over mouse events, just ensure that you call the default implementation whenever moving is required;
- this also means that the `super().mousePressEvent()` *must* be called, since mouseMoveEvents are only received after a mouse button press;
- `x()` e `y()` are existing functions of all QGraphicsItems, and while you can still access them through `self.pos().x()` and `self.pos().y()` there's really no benefit in overwriting those attributes;
- mouse events should not return a `bool`;

```
class Drow_equipent(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, name, brush=Qt.blue, type='эллипс'):
        super().__init__()
        self.setPos(x, y)
        self.penWidth = 1
        self.name = name
        self.h, self.w = h, w
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.signal = Communicate()
        self.setFlags(
            QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges|
            QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable|
            QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        # ...
        self.types = {
            'эллипс': lambda x: x.drawEllipse(0, 0, self.w, self.h),
            'прямоугольник':lambda x: x.drawRect(0, 0, self.w, self.h)
        }

    # ...
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.rotation_:
            self.my_rotation(self.rotation() + 1)
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.rotation_:
            self.rotation_ = False
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos())
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0, 0, self.w, self.h)
```

Finally, creating a widget as a child of a QMainWindow is not enough and is unsupported. You **must** set it as central widget:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

<sup>Also note that, while not essential for running, good code stilying is always suggested; there should *always* be a space after a comma and spaces around equal signs, otherwise reading can be much more uncomfortable, as being able to instantly distinguish objects is very important: seeing `self.x,self.y=x,y` (which is **bad**) is **not** the same as `self.x, self.y = x, y` (which is *good*). Read more on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).</sup>

Comment: This answer is great! Thank you very much for your time and explanation. Without your help, I would no longer
was able to act. I really miss the neatness of the code. Thanks to your answer, further implementation will already be based on the correct concept.