# Why after zooming qraphicsview qraphicsitem leaves traces

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

When moving objects in zoomed mode, objects start to leave traces, but in normal mode everything works perfectly. I thought it was a bouldingRect, however one of my questions provides a normal implementation.

[image: example]

my MRE is in this question [My last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66933578/how-to-save-and-load-position-of-qraphicsitems-to-qraphicscene-or-correctly-dro/66936350#66936350)

Comment: Have you correctly changed the `boundingRect` function and removed all uses to `self.x` and `self.y` as indicated in my answer?

Comment: @musicamante     Everything according to your recipe, maybe this is such a bug at high magnification?

Comment: @musicamante   maybe this occurs when rendering, pianter setting can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the painting of the outline, that always occupies half of the pen width if it draws on the borders. As the documentation about [`boundingRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect) explains:

> Note: For shapes that paint an outline / stroke, it is important to include half the pen width in the bounding rect. It is not necessary to compensate for antialiasing, though.

Since in your case you specified the pen width in the init, you can use that value:

```
    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(
            -self.penWidth / 2, 
            -self.penWidth / 2, 
            self.w + self.penWidth, 
            self.h + self.penWidth)
```

Please note that you actually are *not* using that pen in the painter, so a more correct implementation should be done using `painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.pen_color, self.penWidth))` in the `paint()` function. To slightly improve performance, create a QPen in the init and use that directly for `setPen()`.

Also note that every setting that is changed within the painter (including pen and brush) should not be persistent, so it's always good practice remember to put a `qp.save()` at the beginning of the `paint()` and `qp.restore()` before returning.

Comment: You are the best!)

Comment: Since the question might be useful to other, I'll leave it as it is, but for future reference consider asking clarifications in the original answer. Also, you should edit your question to include a *valid* [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (read my comment there).